# visualizing changes branch in visual studio 2013

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, git-branch, git-gui

it's any way to show history branches project in visual studio 2013?
In git bash console it can be possible by command: `gitk --all`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way, you're better off using another UI, such as tortoisegit (https://tortoisegit.org/) or Atlassian SourceTree (http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)